# Using Excel source on a machine without excel installed in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, excel, ssis, excel-2003

I have made an SSIS package that uses the Excel source to extract data from an Excel 2003 file and inserts it into SQL Server. When executed on production machine it gives and error of 'productleveltoolow'. Excel is not installed on the server. Can this error be due to this reason?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the error?  Are you running through a SQL job or through the SSIS package execution?

Comment: I'm running the package through the SSIS execution GUI.

Answer (score 2):

'productleveltoolow' means the server does not have **SSIS** installed.

http://blogs.msdn.com/michen/archive/2006/11/11/ssis-product-level-is-insufficient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a 64 bit operating system? In that case you have to use the 32bit version of SSIS due to the fact that there is no 64bit driver for Excel (Jet engine), and there never will be.

I do not think this is the answer to your question, but you need to keep this in mind.

/Håkan Winther

Comment: Running it on 32 bit Win Server 2003 machine.