# Populating an Excel template programmatically without Excel installed

Tags: .net, windows, excel, ssis, ole

We have a server which has SQL (specifically SSIS) but no Excel installed (and our policies prohibit this), however data from the SSIS needs to generate a formatted Excel file (with fixed images) and place this in an output directory.

Is it possible to programmatically (using possibly .NET) to populate an Excel template file with values, and source data for charts, without Excel actually being installed on the computer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Excel source on a machine without excel installed in SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298781/using-excel-source-on-a-machine-without-excel-installed-in-ssis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Pubs, 
I think, you may consider using [Aspose.Cell for .NET APIs](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx) as they do not require the availability of Excel application in order to dynamically create, manipulate or convert the spreadsheets. Moreover, these APIs provide a [verity of means to import the data onto the worksheet](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Importing+Data+to+Worksheets) such as from Array, ArrayList, DataTable, DataColumn, DataView, DataGrid, DataReader, & GridView. Furthermore, if you have the pre-configured charts on the spreadsheet, you can simply update the chart's data source to refresh it with new data or create the chart from scratch to finally convert the chart/spreadsheet to a verity of formats. 
I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @Ray, I am afraid, Aspose.Cells APIs currently do not support the Excel's feature of Power Pivot Tables. However, you can simulate it by importing the data to worksheet as data source to the Pivot Table and refresh it after wards. Please note, current implementation of Aspose.Cells APIs do not allow refreshing the data source that is outside the spreadsheet, such as SQL data source.

Answer (score 1):

There are some .NET libraries that can generate, import and export Excel files without Microsoft Office suite installed. For open source, I recommend you to use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), which seems to meet your demand from your description. For commercial version with support, [Spire.Xls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.XLS/) is an option.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Essential XlsIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) can be used to generate Excel files on a server or PC. The library can be used from Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET Webforms, ASP.NET MVC, Silverlight, WinRT, Windows Phone, Windows store Universal and Xamarin applications

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

@Prorata

May I know is Aspose.Cell for .NET APIs support the Power Pivot Data Refresh in a pre-defined Excel template? The Excel may need to connect to SQL database table for the data refresh and using Excel version 2010. will it be possible?

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer. Can you please explain it?